# Skip object in ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs

I have a table with column `names` and a second column with a list of all the names but the tricky part is that each list in the row should skip the name from the first row:

Ex:

Name 1 ---- (Name 2, Name 3)

Name 2 ---- (Name 1, Name 3)

Name 3 ---- (Name 1, Name 2)

I've tried:

```
<md-select ng-model="selectedTopology" multiple>
   <md-option ng-repeat="(k,types) in networkTypes | filter: { name: !networkTypes[k].name } ">{{types.name}}</md-option>
</md-select>
```

This however leaves the list blank, but if I change my filter to:

```
filter: { name: networkTypes[k].name }
```

This shows only the name from the first column

**Edit:**

Structure

```
$scope.networkTypes = [
  {
    name: 'Networktype 1'
  },
  {
    name: 'Networktype 2'
  },
  {
    name: 'Networktype 3'
  }
];
```

Comment: Are you trying to get only 'Networktype 2' and 'Networktype 3' ?

Comment: No, I'm trying to leave out the networktype that is listed in the first column. So leave out Network Type 1 for the first column and so on

Answer (score 0, accepted):

have you tried this :

```
<md-select ng-model="selectedTopology" multiple>
   <md-option ng-repeat="(k,types) in networkTypes" ng-if="types.name !== networkTypes[k].name">{{types.name}}</md-option>
</md-select>
```

Comment: It returns an empty list

Comment: Added it to the post

Comment: Wait, this helped to solve it eventually. I changed it to `!=` and compared it to the first column

Comment: glad you succeed by yourself :)

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
<md-select ng-model="selectedTopology" multiple>
   <md-option ng-repeat="networkTypesObject in networkTypes | filter: { name: !networkTypesObject.name } ">{{networkTypesObject.name}}</md-option>
</md-select>
```

Comment: Returns also an empty list